# Best test runner? (Unit Testing, .NET)

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mbunit

I'm using MBUnit Framework for unit testing and looking for a good test runner.

MbUnit's runner is fast however lacking lots of stuff such as

- You can't set execution path
- It's collapsing all trees in every run which drives me crazy
- And almost all other test runner provides so many extra quite and lovely features

I used Zanebug, but:

- Not properly supported any more, kind of a dead project
- I think it's not compatible with latest MBUnit because it keeps crashing on me
- Got so many weird bugs

Gallio

- Don't know why keeps crashing on startup, (Vista x64)
- I've got it run in another setup, it's about 6 times slower than MBUnit GUI and I've got so many test,

Test Driven .NET addon

- This is great little tool but just for testing one or unit test, doesn't provide a good or VS.NET independent GUI

I'm open to any other free test runner which works with or independent from VS 2008

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I really enjoy NUnit. Now I enjoy even more since I can use it inside the IDE with ReSharper that let me do quick test for a method very fast.

Comment: While NUnit *has* a test runner, it is not a test runner per-se.
ReSharper's the test runner in your case.

Comment: But it doesn't support nunit 2.5 yet...

Comment: This has been written 2 years ago ... thing change but NUnit and ReSharper still a suitable solution. Doesn't support 2.5? Question of time...

Answer (score 13):

Look at [TestDriven](http://testdriven.net/), it adds right-click unit-testing functionality inside Visual Studio. You can right-click a method, a class, a file, a project, or the solution, to run the unit tests that are appropriate. You can also debug, run code coverage, use some of the more popular profilers with it, etc.

Answer (score 11):

Gallio includes ReSharper support.
We are also working to improve performance.

Not sure which version of Icarus you tried but I haven't seen it crash on startup on x64.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The one about nUnit is an answer to another question.

Answer (score 4):

Not free but I'm quite enjoying the CodeRush test runner at the moment.  It integrates well with VS, has support for lots of frameworks and is extensible if it doesn't support yours.

Answer (score 2):

We write our .NET tests in IronPython, which means we can write all our tests using the Python standard library module 'unittest'. The advantage of this is that running tests is a single command. We used to use cruise control and the like, but have since replaced it with about ten lines of Python. This works for both unit tests and functional tests. Obviously this won't work for everyone, but some people will probably find this a productive route to go.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if ReSharper has built in support for MBUnit, but the built in test runner is fantastic.

Comment: doesn't work for MbUnit it complains about file not exist. Also it's not free, is it?

Comment: Actually it is not fantastic, I've had several unit tests fail because of it, while NUnit and TestDriven both report OK. It seems, though I haven't dug far enough down, that ReSharper loads the wrong runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using resharper to run individual tests in IDE, but nunit-console to run all tests for speed.